# In pandas, can I compare 2 columns where first column has instance id and email address in second. Email can be tied to many instance IDs

Tags: python, pandas

Have this table where an email address (col 1) can be associated with multiple instances (col 2). For instance, abc@gmail.com is linked to instance id 158 and 274.

In pandas, how do I look up how many instances / which instances are associated with a particular email address.

[image: data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas  as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('./data/mails.csv')
df
```

```
     email address  instance ID
0    abc@gmail.com          158
1    xyz@gmail.com          189
2    abc@gmail.com          274
3     ab@gmail.com          274
4     bc@gmail.com          274
5   abcd@gmail.com          274
6  axxbc@gmail.com          274
7    xyz@gmail.com          200
```

```
# count instances by mail
print(df.groupby(by='email address').count())
```

```
                 instance ID
email address               
ab@gmail.com               1
abc@gmail.com              2
abcd@gmail.com             1
axxbc@gmail.com            1
bc@gmail.com               1
xyz@gmail.com              2
```

```
# instances by mail
df.pivot_table(index=['email address', 'instance ID'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much @Marcello.  Just what I wanted.